Top navigation bar overlapping sidebar
Tools:

next.js
Tailwind
Shadcn

I'm building a nav that has sticky top bar (shadcn navigation-menu) and sidebar (shadcn sidebar)  that should extend to the bottom of the top nav bar.  No matter how much I tweak the variables in the layout.tsx, I cannot get the sidebar to be fixed below the top nav bar.
Here's the current version of my layout.tsx:
import * as React from "react"
import { AppNavigation } from "@/components/ui/app-navigation"
import { SidebarProvider } from "@/components/ui/sidebar"
import { AppSidebar } from "@/components/ui/app-sidebar"
import { SidebarTrigger } from "@/components/ui/sidebar"
import "../globals.css";

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Next.js Application',
  description: 'A Next.js application with custom navigation',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-background font-brand antialiased">
      <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 w-full h-[72px] border-b bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
        <div className="container flex h-full items-center">
          <AppNavigation />
        </div>
      </header>

      <div className="flex min-h-screen">
        <SidebarProvider>
          {/* Fixed Sidebar */}
          <div className="fixed top-16 left-0 h-[calc(100vh-72px)] w-64">
            <AppSidebar />
          </div>

          <main className="flex-1 ml-64 overflow-y-auto p-6" style={{ marginTop: '72px' }}>
            <SidebarTrigger />
            {children}
          </main>
        </SidebarProvider>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


Flex container - I've tried having the sidebar and main content within and not within the same container
I've played with the container height using tailwind and non-tailwind approaches
I've tweaked flex settings
Tweaked margin on main


For anyone who runs into this issue, modify the sidebar.tsx file:

Replace the inset class with top-16 (adjust accordingly)
Removed the h-svh class

This is the end result:
className={
  cn("duration-200 fixed bottom-0 top-16 z-10 hidden 
      w-[--sidebar-width] transition-[left,right,width] ease-linear 
      md:flex",
  side === "left"
}


You'd want to have the top property of the sidebar be equal to the height of the header. In this case, it would be 72px (also added a background color to see it more clearly):


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="min-h-screen bg-background font-brand antialiased">
  <header class="sticky top-0 z-50 w-full h-[72px] border-b bg-background/95 backdrop-blur supports-[backdrop-filter]:bg-background/60">
    <div class="container flex h-full items-center">
      <AppNavigation>AppNavigation</AppNavigation>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="flex min-h-screen">
    <div class="fixed top-[72px] left-0 h-[calc(100vh-72px)] w-64 bg-red-500">
      <AppSidebar>AppSidebar</AppSidebar>
    </div>

    <main class="flex-1 ml-64 overflow-y-auto p-6" style={{ marginTop: '72px' }}>
      <SidebarTrigger>SidebarTrigger</SidebarTrigger>
      {children}
    </main>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks.  Turns out shadcn's sidebar component was overriding the layout.  For anyone who runs into this issue:
-Replaced the inset class with top-16
-Removed the h-svh class
This is the end result:
className={cn(
"duration-200 fixed bottom-0 top-16 z-10 hidden w-[--sidebar-width] transition-[left,right,width] ease-linear md:flex",
side === "left"
